# How do I set the encoding for a .net binary file transfer

Tags: .net, encoding, ftp, binary

I can successfully upload text files using .net ftp
 but now want to upload a graphics (.png) image.
How should I set the stream encoding ?

What I have for text (in Apl script ) :

sourceStream ← '.net' ⎕new 'System.IO.StreamReader' Localpathfilename
encoding←'.NET' ⎕NEW 'System.Text.ASCIIEncoding'

I then lose bytes from the transferred binary file.
I have also tried omitting the encoding line.

cheers, Beau

More info :
This is the core of the Ascii version, written in AplX .net - 
It works fine 
- now I need a BinaryReader version.
Help appreciated

```
  ftp←'.net' ⎕call 'System.Net.WebRequest.Create' Remotepathfilename
  ftp.Method←'.net' ⎕call 'System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp.UploadFile'
  ftp.Credentials←'.net' ⎕new 'System.Net.NetworkCredential' Username Password

sourceStream ← '.net' ⎕new 'System.IO.StreamReader' Localpathfilename
encoding←'.NET' ⎕NEW 'System.Text.ASCIIEncoding'

fileContents ← encoding.GetBytes.⎕REF 
sourceStream.ReadToEnd 
sourceStream.Close 
ftp.ContentLength ← fileContents.Length 
:try
  stream←ftp.GetRequestStream
:catchall
  .....
```

Here is what I have now been trying, based on vb code at :

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread#Y1035

Dim fs As FileStream
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
```

So I have tried :

```
fileStream ← '.net' ⎕new 'System.IO.File' 
fileStream.OpenRead  Localpathfilename
```

Here are the error messages :

```
Constructor on type 'System.IO.File' not found.
DOMAIN ERROR
net_ftp_putfile[72] fileStream←'.net' ⎕new 'System.IO.File'
```

Comment: Use UTF8 encoding. ASCII encoding will cause problems and you will end up pulling your hair out trying to fix this (It happened to me)

Comment: what does your ftp code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Binary files don't have "encoding" unless you want to transform the data to survive a lossy transfer medium (such as 7-bit BBSes or MTAs, where you'd want to Base64 encode your data). Encoding is for text files.

Don't use `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter` for working with binary data. The classes aren't named well, they should be called `TextStreamReader` and `TextStreamWriter` to better reflect what they do. If you've got a Stream you want to work with then you should use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`.

Comment: Hmm I am still having problems. I gather this should look like :     new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)); Can anyone give me an idea of what this looks like one step at a time, I am having problems translating it into object based AplX, thanks, Beau

Comment: The Ascii version, which works fine - now I need a BinaryReader version :
  ftp←'.net' ⎕call 'System.Net.WebRequest.Create' Remotepathfilename
      ftp.Method←'.net' ⎕call 'System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp.UploadFile'
      ftp.Credentials←'.net' ⎕new 'System.Net.NetworkCredential' Username Password

sourceStream ← '.net' ⎕new 'System.IO.StreamReader' Localpathfilename
encoding←'.NET' ⎕NEW 'System.Text.ASCIIEncoding'

fileContents ← encoding.GetBytes.⎕REF 
sourceStream.ReadToEnd 
sourceStream.Close 
ftp.ContentLength ← fileContents.Length 
:try
  stream←ftp.GetRequestStream
:catchall
.....

Comment: `  ftp←'.net' ⎕call 'System.Net.WebRequest.Create' Remotepathfilename
      ftp.Method←'.net' ⎕call 'System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp.UploadFile'
      ftp.Credentials←'.net' ⎕new 'System.Net.NetworkCredential' Username Password

sourceStream ← '.net' ⎕new 'System.IO.StreamReader' Localpathfilename
encoding←'.NET' ⎕NEW 'System.Text.ASCIIEncoding'

fileContents ← encoding.GetBytes.⎕REF 
sourceStream.ReadToEnd 
sourceStream.Close 
ftp.ContentLength ← fileContents.Length 
:try
  stream←ftp.GetRequestStream
:catchall
.....
`

Comment: `code  ftp←'.net' ⎕call 'System.Net.WebRequest.Create' Remotepathfilename
      ftp.Method←'.net' ⎕call 'System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp.UploadFile'
      ftp.Credentials←'.net' ⎕new 'System.Net.NetworkCredential' Username Password

sourceStream ← '.net' ⎕new 'System.IO.StreamReader' Localpathfilename
encoding←'.NET' ⎕NEW 'System.Text.ASCIIEncoding'

fileContents ← encoding.GetBytes.⎕REF 
sourceStream.ReadToEnd 
sourceStream.Close 
ftp.ContentLength ← fileContents.Length 
:try
  stream←ftp.GetRequestStream
:catchall
.....
`

Comment: <code>   ftp←'.net' ⎕call 'System.Net.WebRequest.Create' Remotepathfilename
    ftp.Method←'.net' ⎕call   'System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp.UploadFile'
    ftp.Credentials←'.net' ⎕new 'System.Net.NetworkCredential' Username Password
    
    sourceStream ← '.net' ⎕new 'System.IO.StreamReader' Localpathfilename
    encoding←'.NET' ⎕NEW 'System.Text.ASCIIEncoding'
    
    fileContents ← encoding.GetBytes.⎕REF 
    sourceStream.ReadToEnd 
    sourceStream.Close 
    ftp.ContentLength ← fileContents.Length 
    :try
    stream←ftp.GetRequestStream
    :catchall
    ..... </code>

Comment: Apl. To be precise, AplX by MicroApl. Variables can be multi-dimensional arrays. Operators can act on functions : +/ A sums rows in A, x/[1] A multiplies columns in A. +.x is an inner product, o.x is an outer product. Does .net, talks to gate arrays, builds GUIs.

Comment: You're not using the `File` class correctly. It's a static class, you shouldn't construct an instance of it (in fact you can't, that's why you're getting that error message).